# laravel Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap

Tags: laravel-5

when i try run gulp in terminal i got this error message:

> laravel Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap

although the node_modules folders is already exist.

can some one help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed

just i double check my bootstrap included path at the gulpfile.js to be like this

```
elixir.config.css.sass.pluginOptions.includePaths = ['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets'];
```

hope this help